# Differences between Spark's Row and InternalRow types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Currently Spark has two implementations for Row:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow
```

What is the need to have both of them? Do they represent the same encoded entities but one used internally (internal APIs) and the other is used with the external APIs?

Answer (score 0):

[Row](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala) is the stable version implementation of (well..) Row... However, [InternalRow](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow.scala) as the name sounds, is to be used internally within Spark SQL. I'm quoting the documentation from InternalRow below:

```
/**
 * An abstract class for row used internally in Spark SQL, which only contains the columns as
 * internal types.
 */
abstract class InternalRow extends SpecializedGetters with Serializable {
```

Comment: Not quite - `Row` an abstraction for user API, not implementation. Other than that you are correct.